# Kotlin forEach order

Tags: arrays, loops, foreach, kotlin

Does Kotlin forEach iterate through an array in real order of array or it may be sometimes in another order? I mean does this always print 1,2,3,...9 or it may print something like this 1,5,3,4,...

```
val numbers: Array<Int> = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    numbers.forEach({(number: Int) ->
        Log.d(tag,number)
    })
```

[Kotlin forEach reference](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/for-each.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`forEach` iterates in order from first to last element; source code:

`Collections.kt`

```
/**
 * Performs the given [action] on each element.
 */
@kotlin.internal.HidesMembers
public inline fun <T> Iterable<T>.forEach(action: (T) -> Unit): Unit {
    for (element in this) action(element)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, it keeps real order. Look at implementation:

```
public inline fun IntArray.forEach(action: (Int) -> Unit): Unit {
        for (element in this) action(element)
    }
```

For loop uses iterator of the array, which keeps order too.

Answer (score 2):

These are two separate questions. Yes, as pointed out by the other answers, it keeps the order. But since `forEach` doesn't print anything, it all depends on the implementation of the printing.

For example, this will not always print the numbers 1 to 10 in order, even though it uses `forEach`:

```
fun myPrint(i: Int) = launch { println(i) }

(1..10).forEach { n -> myPrint(n) }
```

Since we don't know how your `Log.d(...)` is implemented, we can't be sure.